# Input type="file" onclick works, but file selection doesnt show

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<a id="newPhoto" class="new-image no-expand">
    <input onclick="alert('cocos')" type="file" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1500"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-upload clickable no-expand"
            style="font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <div title="Remove" class="btn-remove">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: white"></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Now when clicking the `input`, the visual effect of `click` on the button is triggered, aswell as the `onclick` event handler, but for some reason the popup dialog to make me select a file doesn't. I have also tried to remove any css, and make sure that that exact item is clicked, and that it is not covered by another div or stuff like that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that I was nesting an `input` inside an `a`. It is not valid HTML. However, it would've probably worked if I wasn't also using Angular, which causes any click on any `<a>` to do nothing if it doesn't have a `src` attribute.

```
var htmlAnchorDirective = valueFn({
restrict: 'E',
compile: function(element, attr) {
  if (!attr.href && !attr.xlinkHref) {
    return function(scope, element) {
      // If the linked element is not an anchor tag anymore, do nothing
      if (element[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') return;

      // SVGAElement does not use the href attribute, but rather the 'xlinkHref' attribute.
      var href = toString.call(element.prop('href')) === '[object SVGAnimatedString]' ?
                 'xlink:href' : 'href';
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        // if we have no href url, then don't navigate anywhere.
        if (!element.attr(href)) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    };
  }
}
});
```

Changing the container to a div solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the file dialogue box appears after you click OK button in the alert box.[Click Here](https://codepen.io/DivyaSekaran/pen/KzrKeL)

```
Please see my code in the above Link.
```